# Growth and Decay

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble with this problem.

In 1994, rock climbers in southern France stumbled on a cave containing prehistoric cave paintings. A C^14 analysis carried out by French archaeologist Helene Valladas showed that the paintings are between 29,700 and 32,400 years old, much older than any previously known human art. Given that the C^14 to C^12 ratio of the atmosphere is R = 10^-12, what C^14 to C^12 ratio did Valladas find in the charcoal specimen dated to 30100 years?

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You assume the $C^{14}$ to $C^{12}$ ratio was $10^{-12}$ at the time the wood grew.  The $C^{14}$ has been decaying, so the amount is now $10^{-12}$ times the fraction that is left.  You need to look up the half-life of $C^{14}$, then figure out how many half-lives it has been since the wood grew.

Comment: If there has been about 5.3 halflives since it grew, do you multiply that by 10^-12.

Comment: 5.3 is a reasonable number.  A half-life means that the amount is reduced by half in that time.  After three half lives, there is one eighth the original.

Comment: So I need to multiply 10^-12 by one eighth?

Comment: No, you have more than three half-lives.  What do you know of [exponential decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) and [half-life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life)?

Comment: Okay so if I have 5 halflives, that is 1/32, correct?

Comment: That is correct.  For $n$ half-lives you have $2^{-n}$ of the original left.  In your problem, you have more than $5$, but your calculator probably has a $y^x$ button.  Mine shows you have about $\frac 1{40}$ left

Comment: I got 2.5*10^-14 and it said that is wrong

Comment: That looks fine to me, unless there is argument over how many figures to show.  Using 5730 years I get $5.253$ half lives and $2.622\cdot 10^{-14}$ but you only have three places in the age